# Why is the Apple menu icon in the wrong place on my secondary monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, icon

So I'm running Mavericks and absolutely love having menus on each monitor. I have two external monitors working with my 15" Macbook Pro, and one of the two monitors has the top menu kind of messed up. The Apple icon is way over on the right, and is actually overlapping with some of my other icons. I've removed the Apple TV icon to prevent some of the overlap, but I can't figure out for the life of me why the Apple icon is in the wrong place or how to fix it.

[image: Apple icon in wrong location]

I have one monitor attached via standard DVI adaptor through the Thunderbolt connection. The other, that is having this issue, is using a StarTech USB to DVI adapter. Could that be causing this issue? I'm not sure how it would... but that's the only difference between the two setups that I can find for the secondary displays.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing (at least temporarily) all your non-Apple menu bar icons, and then restart your machine.   In Mavericks  you should have two identical menu bars.